# EXIF properties for date missing

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm creating an image with attributes from JPEG data wrapped in an NSData object. I seem to be having a problem setting the date property in the EXIF data.

```
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[EXIFDictionary setValue:dateString forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal];
[EXIFDictionary setValue:dateString forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized];
[EXIFDictionary setValue:@"My comment" forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifCameraOwnerName];
[metadata setObject:EXIFDictionary forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];
```

When I open the image in Preview, I can see the user comments, but neither of the dates will appear.

Has anyone had any success with setting this?